# Understand Hooked syscalls - Do win32 api always call system ones in ntdll.dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, operating-system, antivirus

I wrote a keylogger that hooks keystrokes. I learned about the AV's detection with hooked syscall and wanted to know if my keyboard hook is side by side with the AV's...so can AV monitor that function?. I have opened the `ntdll.dll` file but I have not found the functions that I use to do the hook. Does this mean that win32s don't always call system functions?

For example, this are the functions that I used but I don't find them in `ntdll.dll`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

Comment: Why should an AV product install a keyboard hook? And your code snippet shows that the used functions are implemented in user32.dll not in ntdll.dll. if you want to know how the hooks are implemented you can open user32.dll in an decompiler like Ghidra or IDA.

Answer (score 0):

Check out syswhispers and see if you can generate "Ntcall..." code.

https://github.com/jthuraisamy/SysWhispers

It rewrites win32 calls into their Nt equivalent. Syswhispers3 redirects the system calls so that it looks like the call originates from an NTDLL module address and AV's do not flag it.

But, in this case as the "hook" functions are in user32.dll they probably are not in ntdll.dll as well.